A light of/from or a light to/for
In Isaiah 42:6 (ESV)
the following phrase:

“I am the Lord; I have called you[a] in righteousness;
I will take you by the hand and keep you; I will give you as a covenant for the people,
a light for the nations"

Is there anything in the hebrew text that denotes that the light is for/to the nations as opposed to the light is of/from the nations? Or could it also be both?

The final four words of Isa 42:6 form two two-word phrases with identical grammatical construction as follows:

לִבְרִ֥ית עָ֖ם = as a covenant of people
לְאֹ֥ור גֹּויִֽם = as a light of nations

Both are noun construct chains, and both begin with the lambda preposition meaning "to, for, in regard to ..."; hence the translation above.  This is a common theme in the Bible as follows:

Isa 49:6 - He says: “It is not enough for You to be My Servant, to raise up the tribes of Jacob, and to restore the protected ones of Israel. I will also make You a light for the nations, to bring My salvation to the ends of the earth.”
Isa 51:4 - Pay attention to Me, My people, and listen to Me, My nation; for a law will go out from Me, and My justice will become a light to the nations; I will bring it about quickly.

Jesus, Paul and Barnabas quote these verses:

Acts 13:47 - For this is what the Lord has commanded us: ‘I have made you a light for the Gentiles, to bring salvation to the ends of the earth.’”
Matt 5:14-16 - You are the light of the world. A city on a hill cannot be hidden. Neither do people light a lamp and put it under a basket. Instead, they set it on a stand, and it gives light to everyone in the house. In the same way, let your light shine before men, that they may see your good deeds and glorify your Father in heaven.

The source of this "Light" and salvation to the world is also stated:

Ps 27:1 - The LORD is my light and my salvation—whom shall I fear? The LORD is the stronghold of my life—whom shall I dread?
Micah 7:8 - Do not gloat over me, my enemy! Though I have fallen, I will arise; though I sit in darkness, the LORD will be my light.
John 1:4 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men.
John 1:9 - The true Light who gives light to every man was coming into the world.
John 8:12 - Therefore Jesus spoke to them again, saying, "I am the light of the world. The one following Me shall not walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life."

